# Getting the URL details - Laravel

Tags: laravel, partials

I am working on a Laravel project, where I want to toggle partials based on the URL data like

```
foo.bar.com/#itemone/create
foo.bar.com/#itemone/view
```

Basically, I want to pass whether it is create or view to the partials like this

```
 @include('partials.layouts._core_activity_header',['layout_type' => "create"])
```

How do I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the route name

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getName()
```

this will return the route alias